# Insert unique values in Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have one array. The function gets called continuously from backend service. 
I want to push unique values in one object. My code is

```
currentValue =  pointerToVisconCtrl.MappedVariableObj.value;
var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
seconds = parseInt(seconds);
graphDataObject.push({timestamp : seconds, value : currentValue});
```

Please guide me to enter only unique currentValue and seconds value in graphDataObject

Comment: unique as in both if obj contains {timestamp : 11, value :100}, then next timestamp should nt contain 11 or  {timestamp : 11, value :100} shouldnt be allowed

Comment: what I meant was should both keys be unique or just one?

Comment: No i want {timestamp : 11, value :100} only for one time, it should be pushed in array.

Comment: one key should be unique

Comment: In graphDataObject - the currentvalue and timestamp (seconds) are inserted dynamically. The graphdataobject is filling too fast and duplicate values are inserted in graphdataobject. I want only unique values to be inserted in graphdataobject array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var finalArr = graphDataObject.filter(function(d){
if(d.value == currentValue){ return d;}
});

if(finalArr.length == 0){
graphDataObject.push({timestamp : seconds, value : currentValue});
}
```

Comment: what is the output of above code?

Comment: In graphDataObject - the currentvalue and timestamp (seconds) are inserted dynamically. The graphdataobject is filling too fast and duplicate values are inserted in graphdataobject. I want only unique values to be inserted in graphdataobject array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter function in the javascript array like below to check if a particular object exists or not:

```
var dataObject = graphDataObject.filter(function(el){
      return el.timestamp == seconds && el.value == currentValue; //you can check only one object if you want here
 });
if(dataObject.length > 0)
{
  //the object exists in the array
}
else{
 graphDataObject.push({timestamp : seconds, value : currentValue}); //push object to the array.
}
```

Comment: This searches the entire array unconditionally. [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns immediately upon finding a match.

Comment: @mohit In your filter condition, you can take seconds and value both. so your dataObject length always 0 because seconds always be different

Comment: in graphDataObject - duplicate values are inserted continuesly. I want new object of currentValue and Seconds pair. The values should be unique and unique values should be inserted in array continuosly.

Comment: @Nishant, conditions can be changed as per need. For this particular case, I think using Array.prototype.some is better, since only one match is enough to decide whether to push or not.

Comment: @Rajesh, if you want your both objects to be unique then my solution should work for you. However, you can use 'some' instead of 'filter' prototype to make it more efficient.

Comment: In graphDataObject - the currentvalue and timestamp (seconds) are inserted dynamically. The graphdataobject is filling too fast and duplicate values are inserted in graphdataobject. I want only unique values to be inserted in graphdataobject array.

Answer (score 0):

Use filter function along with || to avoid duplication

```js
let graphDataObject = [{timestamp : 11, value : 11},{timestamp : 4, value : 44},{timestamp : 2, value : 22},{timestamp : 3, value : 24}]


let newObject = {timestamp : 11, value : 24}


let result = graphDataObject.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.timestamp == newObject["timestamp"] || obj.value == newObject["value"];
})

if(result.length > 1) {
  // already present.. do your logic
}
```

Comment: In graphDataObject - the currentvalue and timestamp (seconds) are inserted dynamically. The graphdataobject is filling too fast and duplicate values are inserted in graphdataobject. I want only unique values to be inserted in graphdataobject array.

Comment: is my code not working? put my code inside my function and before every insertion into graphobject call the function; in the commented line, decide whether or not to insert..